# Mocking KafkaAvroDeserializer for unit testing using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-kafka, mockito, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to unit test a class which uses KafkaAvroDeserializer to deserialize an object. I would like to mock the KafkaAvroDeserializer so that I can test the business logic. However, when I am trying to mock KafkaAvroDeserializer, I get the following error:

> Underlying exception : org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Could not modify all classes [class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer, interface org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer, interface java.io.Closeable, class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer, class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe, interface java.lang.AutoCloseable]

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
> Mockito cannot mock this class: class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.

Mockito version: 4.8.0
JDK: 8 and tried 11 too.

Any help here is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest looking at the existing tests in the schema registry project

Comment: referring to this? https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/4f305070b42c5d25c14f874a9a41a181425771db/schema-rules/src/test/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/rules/cel/CelExecutorTest.java

Comment: That is the correct repo, but not tests for the serializer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mocking the `KafkaAvroDeserializer`, it will probably work better if you use the [MockSchemaRegistry](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/client/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/client/MockSchemaRegistryClient.java).

You do this by supplying the following config `schema.registry.url=mock://deserializer-test` to the deserializer.  That way you're still using SR but it's in-memory so completely unit-testable.

HTH,
Bill